# How to revert changes to just a block of code in Visual Studio using Git

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am used to VisualSVN (Visual Studio plug-in for SVN) feature to select a part of code and revert changes to it (by shortcut CTRL+ALT+Z) and not affect the changes in other parts of the same file.

Is there something similar for Git? Or I have to revert a whole file?

Comment: I don't know anything about Git plugins for Visual Studio, but in IntelliJ or Eclipse (Java based IDEs), you could simply open up a side-by-side diff of a given file against another commit, and then selectively choose to bring over how ever many lines you want.  There is probably a way to do the same in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, that workaround is what I do at the moment. I look the diff and copy over the part of code that I want to revert. It's all without leaving the VS, but since I'm used to a shortcut, it feels unproductive.

Comment: I don't really consider this a workaround, but rather the best way to use Git, but this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: git diff margin

Answer (score 7):

Some IDE such as Android Studio the shortcut CTRL+ALT+Z to revert on block of change is default function, you can use it since the IDE was installed.

But unfortunately, if you want to do the same thing in the VS Code, you should set this by yourself.

1. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on macOS)
2. Search "revert" as keywords
3. "Git: Revert selected Ranged" will be found
4. Allocate shortcut CTRL+ALT+Z to it
5. Enjoy!

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is a little old, but this is what worked for me in **Visual Studio Code** (not sure if this would work in Visual Studio as they are separate applications):

1. **Open the Source Control panel** (shows the list of files with changes).
2. Make sure the file that contains the block of code you want to revert is NOT staged. If it is staged, unstage it. You can easily stage it again.
3. **Right click** on the file from #2 and select **"Open File"**.
4. Find the block that you want to change.
5. Locate the blue bar to the left of the code block (should be just to the right of the code line number/s).
6. Left (single) click the blue bar from the previous step.
7. You should see a section pop up that shows the diff. If you don't see it, you may need to repeat #6 - I'm guessing the window pane needs focus first or something like that.
8. Towards the right you should see some icons that look like a Plus, Undo, Down Arrow, Up Arrow, Close.
9. Click the "Undo" icon to revert the code block. Follow any prompts to confirm.

The code block should be reverted. Hopefully this helps someone even if it doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code, and that does not work in Visual Studio.

Comment: I got here looking for vscode solutions, so this is useful.  Unfortunately this change does not seem to get stored in the undo buffer (vscode 1.41.1), so this interface is good for reverting changes, but not for un-reverting them.  My workaround is to have a copy of the new file somewhere else, and copy it back over after checking that each reverted change does not cause the new problem that crept in.